# Search 'inquestion' option is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Just now [discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51347/duplicate-answers-are-tolerated/51350#51350) that *inquestion* is highly sensitive to referrer and just doesn't work in many situations.

Given https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion:1711+mythical+man+month:

- An offsite referrer yields no results if it resembles `/questions/{ID}`.  (The wrong ID is used?)  Reproduce: use the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion:1711+mythical+man+month) from this MSO question.
- No referrer yields a [server error](https://stackoverflow.com/error).  Reproduce: copy-paste the [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion:1711+mythical+man+month) into a new window.
- Otherwise yields results from many other questions; appears that *inquestion* is simply ignored.  Reproduce: use the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion:1711+mythical+man+month) from the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/51353/revisions) page.

While *inquestion:this* does work from the question page, it fails when refining the search.  Reproduce: change the sort order to newest or votes.  The query terms should instead have "this" replaced with the question ID when first submitted, which has the added bonus of being able to share working URLs.

Comment: @Jeff: Non-"this" queries are also broken.  In fact, that's the majority of the cases I list.

Answer (score 1):

I see the issue, and have checked in a fix.

Comment: Using *inquestion:this* from a question page then clicking a sort tab is still broken.