# Is a "sum up" answer with little to no added value worth flagging?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers

I've read everything I found on this topic but nothing addressing this particular issue:

There's a popular question with a popular and accepted answer that correctly answers the question asked and has a short but healthy comment thread.

One of the other replies, the reason I'm asking about this, is essentially this:

> Short answer!
>
> Thanks to all the great and right answers above. I read a few of them and wanted a quick short and sweet solution. So, this is a short answer to summarize what has been explained above.
>
> [And here the information provided in the accepted answer stripped off the valuable observations of when it works, how to use it etc.]
>
> Cheers!

The user has 2'2k of rep, the same as me, and I know not to answer like that. It just looks like an attempt to collect cheap reputation (which hasn't worked out).

Now reading what I just wrote it seems clearer that it shouldn't be there, but I rather get feedback on what's the best course of action here.

Comment: If you don't flag it, it might slip under mods' noses.  If you *do* flag it, the worst that can happen is the mods feel it's okay.  Or is that not how flags work?

Comment: Related: [How to flag duplicate answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180207/how-to-flag-duplicate-answers?rq=1)

Comment: Crap, I didn't find that post. It's from 2014 though. I'll apply what's answered there, but shouldn't this be evolved? We see this fairly often

Comment: If you decide to leave it, at least replace the intro fluff with "This is a summary of the answers by Foonly, Bardoyle and Howe." and link to thise answers. And remove the "cheers". Those eduts make it an even better short summary.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is kind of case-by-case. It's not really possible to make a general statement about "summary" answers.

At the end of the day, whether you agree with the below points or not, it really comes down to this: When you step back and consider it from the POV of others, does the answer add something that helps future readers? Does it *improve* the overall quality of the Q&A? If so, it's a good answer. If not, flag or vote accordingly.

Some examples, in my opinion anyways:

- If the answer is literally nothing more than a list of links to the other answers or some commentary on which answer(s) somebody found valuable, this doesn't really add anything. The page itself is *already* a list of answers with indicators of which ones people found valuable. Your options are:

  - NAA flag if you truly think it's problematic and you are *certain* that it's not an attempt to answer the question.
  - Downvote.
  - Do nothing. Ultimately the more useful answers will trump this one in votes.
- If the answer is just a summary of *one* existing answer, I would certainly flag that NAA unless it adds something useful.
- On the other hand, if it's a short summary of multiple other answers (and whether or not it's by the OP of the original question may or may not affect the judgment here, as well as whether or not it has received upvotes -- keep reading), this is a hint that at least one person found that there so many wildly varying other answers that a summary was *useful*. Further upvotes are evidence that it is indeed useful. If the summary helps readers, in my opinion, it's doing good. But I feel this case is *extremely* rare, and definitely doesn't justify it in general. I also feel like if it's the OP coming back and saying "Here was my final solution, and I also considered these other options", that is a plus.
- Then again, illustrating the case-by-case nature of this, if a "useful" summary as per the previous point is posted on, say, a really old question, well, that's evidence that perhaps it isn't so useful to a general reader, as so much time has gone past without anybody *else* feeling the need to do that.

However, the third case above *may* be indicative of a deeper issue (*maybe*, again, case-by-case). For example, if there are so many existing answers with such varying content that a reader thought to themselves "This is nuts, I need to summarize this", this could be an indicator that the question itself was rather broad or opinion based.

Still, it's fuzzy. No matter how you feel about it, I don't think a general consensus can or should be reached on this due to all of the other variables. So you should really just do what *you* think is right. If the *community* feels it is or isn't useful in general, flags and votes and such will reflect that in the long run and it will meet its natural fate. Remember: If you don't feel certain about a flag, you can always downvote, do nothing, or even leave a comment if you feel like you can provide constructive input.